# Can Image.open (using Pillow python library) accept user input using st.file_uploader in Streamlit?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, streamlit

I have tried multiple variation to try to get user input of image using `st.file_uploader` in Streamlit.

`Image.open('Logo.png')` only works, however `Image.open` shows you error if you use the variable to get user input.

The code I tried:

```py
import qrcode
from qrcode.image.styledpil import StyledPilImage
from qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers import RoundedModuleDrawer, GappedSquareModuleDrawer
from  qrcode.image.styles.colormasks import SolidFillColorMask

Uploadimage = st.file_uploader('Choose the image to upload')
if Uploadimage is not None:
   image_file = Uploadimage.getvalue()

im = Image.open(image_file)

qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=4,error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H)

qr.add_data('http://www.google.com')


qr_img = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, module_drawer=GappedSquareModuleDrawer(), color_mask=ImageColorMask(color_mask_path = im ), embeded_image_path= im)

qr_img.save("xx.png")
qr_img
```

Errors shown:
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

I was expecting that the above code to accept the user input of image.

Comment: Your question is not very easy to understand. Please show the error and the code that causes it.

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
the code I tried is mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Import `io` to convent Uploadimage (byte data) to [**`BinaryIO`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)

```py
import io
from PIL import Image
import streamlit as st

Uploadimage = st.file_uploader('Choose the image to upload')
if Uploadimage is not None:
    # To read file as bytes:
    imagefile = io.BytesIO(Uploadimage.read())

    im = Image.open(imagefile)
    # Do something with im
    st.image(im)
```

[image]

Comment: Not working giving the same error 
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'"

Comment: Edit your question to include more code and the complete `Error Traceback`, tell us how and where your are using the image file. Otherwise we wouldn't really be able to offer a solution to your problem.

Comment: Update the code in the Body of the Question